# Ways to highlight during a presentation

Tags: macos, keynote, accessibility, highlights

I miss the old [*OmniDazzle*](https://support.omnigroup.com/omnidazzle-troubleshooting/) product from [The Omni Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Omni_Group) that let us transform the mouse pointer in a variety of ways, some silly but some quite practical. Worked well for highlighting areas of the screen to focus the attention of the audience during a talk or presentation.

I'm looking to make the mouse pointer more obvious, or darken the screen while keeping one region bright, or drawing colored crayon/marker lines, and so on.

**Accessibility features**

I'm open to accessibility features in macOS that could work to focus the audience’s attention.

**Keynote features**

Mainly I use [Apple Keynote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keynote_(presentation_software)) for presentations. If Keynote has dynamic tools for focusing the audience’s attention, that would be helpful.

I also show other apps such as [programmers’ IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s during a talk, so using it outside of Kenote is ideal.

**Other solutions**

Are there other ways or other apps to accomplish this goal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of presentation?  PowerPoint, Keynote? Just mirroring the screen?  If you use Keynote with iOS you can use the 'laser' pointer or draw on the screen.  All depends on what your requirements are.  Cheers

Comment: @bjbk See edits. Mainly Keynote, but also other apps.

Comment: Do we assume that everytime someone offers a comment with a possible solution you are just going to add it to your answer? That seems to be a bit de-motivating...

Comment: @Solar Mike, What problem do you see with the edit Basil Bourque made? It addresses the comment made by bjbk and adds value to his question. This is in part what comment are for, and to that I say to Basil Bourque, +1 for improving the quality of the question being asked!

Comment: adds an answer into his question...

Comment: @SolarMike I edited the Question to be more specific, added details, while maintaining the essence of the issue. As user3439894 said, that is the point of comments on a Stack Exchange. If I am confused, please cite some documentation such as the Help section or Meta site to correct me. As for "adds an answer into his question", you're point escapes me.

Comment: The basic premise of the site is that the best answers are voted to the top - unless I have misunderstood how it works , so it just seems that if I wished to add an answer it would just get incorporated and loose its value.

Comment: @Solar Mike, There's absolutely nothing wrong with the edit he made to his question, nor did he answer his own question, nor has an answer been offered in the comments. I'm quite sure that if an appropriate answer gets posted, as an answer not a comment, it will get the proper attention. It's evident from his question history, he knows what he's doing. He has up voted and or marked as accepted the majority of answers posted to his questions. So I don't understand why you make a comment like "so it just seems that if I wished to add an answer it would just get incorporated and loose its value."

Answer (score 10):

For **Keynote** presentations, by using an iOS device as a remote one can draw or use a ‘laser’ pointer on the slides. Although not as elegant as drawing focus to an element, it certainly grabs attention.

**iOS Remote:**

[image: laser pointer]

**Display with drawing to highlight:**

[image: drawing]

Answer (score 9):

#### [Mouseposé](https://itunes.apple.com/app/mousepose/id405904955?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D8)

> When turned on, it dims the screen and puts a spotlight on the area
> around the mouse pointer, easily guiding the audience‘s attention to
> an area of interest.

[image]

Additionally, it has the mouse click visualization and typing visualization - both allowing your audience to see what you click and type.

They have a [video](https://www.boinx.com/mousepose/inaction/) on their site  that shows the software in action.

#### [Ink2Go](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ink2go/id413610320?mt=12)

> Ink2Go is an extremely simple and powerful screen annotation and
> recording software. Using Ink2Go you can easily write on top of any
> other application currently active on the desktop, even on a running
> video.

There is a [15 day free trail](http://ink2go.org/) available at their website. They have both Windows and Mac versions.  In addition, there is a number of [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ink2go) videos showing the product in action

[image]

This one may be a bit of overkill given all the features, but I have seen this at work in an education setting and it's excellent software.

Answer (score 4):

## Logitech Spotlight Presentation Remote

Apple says:

> With Spotlight you can take a giant step beyond traditional laser pointing. This advanced system lets you precisely highlight or magnify areas of focus in pixel-perfect detail. It's clearly visible to both the audience in the room and everyone watching via video conference.

[At the Apple Store](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HKZD2ZM/A/logitech-spotlight-presentation-remote)

[At Logitech.com](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/spotlight-presentation-remote)

[image: Logitech Spotlight Remote]

Comment: Wow, this a clever idea… and, what a price.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this recently launched app. It matches your requirement of working outside of keynote and is great for IDE.

## [Presentify](https://presentify.compzets.com)

A simple mac app for screen annotation, cursor highlight, and more. You can draw on any screen and also highlight your mouse pointer or cursor to better engage your audience in the presentation. It also has a whiteboard feature that might be helpful for online classes.

[image]

Demo: https://youtu.be/2WvmLwohIF0
Mac App Store: https://apps.apple.com/app/presentify/id1507246666
Setapp: https://go.setapp.com/stp285?refAppID=401

Note: Setapp is like Netflix for apps. You pay a monthly subscription fee and access all the apps on its store for free.

*Disclosure: I am the developer of this app.*

Comment: It works really great with KeyNote! I don't understand how is that it does not support that natively but its cool to have this.

Answer (score 1):

[Remote Buddy](https://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/) has a feature called "mousespot" that fades the screen except for an area around the mouse.  It also visualizes mouse clicks with a red dot.  These are both functions associated with the "virtual mouse" behaviour of the remote.

Remote Buddy is basically a driver for using all kinds of remotes to control your Mac, including an iOS device, or a virtual keyboard (keyboard shortcuts).  It supports over 100 Apps (not just Keynote or PowerPoint) as well as simulating keyboard and mouse input, or AppleScript and UI controls, so it is very versatile and highly customizable.  Useful for presentations, or controlling movies from your couch.

Answer (score 1):

[IPEVO Annotator](https://www.ipevo.com/software/annotator) is the tool I use for the same purpose you ask. It is free.